# How to tell if data is filtered well?

Tags: r, time-series

I have about 3 hours worth of 3-axis accelerometer, gyroscope and compass data taken at subsecond intervals. I'm fully aware that this data needs to be filtered and that there are a shedload of methods for filtering it (FFT, ARMA, et al). How can I tell from my data or a plot thereof, which is the "best" filter to use?

For example, if I have 3 hours of a jog on the street and I'd like to track the length of the jogger's stride. I'm thinking I would integrate the gyroscope to get the absolute direction and then double integrate the raw accelerometer data to get distance. Finally, divide the result of this by the number of troughs in the spline encompassing the points (as they would represent mainly downward acceleration). Is this the correct approach? Many thanks!

http://analysis.d8u.us/~hdiwan/accelAndGyro.png

Comment: I think this is a show-and-tell kind of question. Maybe plot the accelerometer data, by axis v. time and give us a peek? (a faceted plot, or three plots using the same timescale)

Comment: There you are, Brandon